# counter doesn't correctly counter for both uppercase char and lowercase char

Tags: java

Write a program that uses a Scanner object to first read in a number that represents the size (n) of an array of Strings. Create an array of Strings that uses the first number as the size. You will then read in (n) cities all on the same line and store them in the array. Finally, you will read in a char (same line as the cities). Then program will then go through the array of cities and print the screen the number of times the char is in the city. Make sure you deal with case (A != a).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = scanner.nextInt();
        String myarray[] = new String[length];
        char ch;
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
            myarray[i]=scanner.next();
         }
    
    ch= scanner.next().charAt(0);
    char ch1= Character.toUpperCase(ch);
    char ch2= Character.toLowerCase(ch);
    for(int y=0; y<myarray.length; y++){
      int counter=0;
      for(int z=0; z<myarray.length; z++){
        
        if(myarray[y].charAt(z)==ch1){
          counter++;
        }else if(myarray[y].charAt(z)==ch2){
          counter++;
        }
      }
      System.out.print(counter+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Example Input:

> 4
>
> Toronto Halifax Truro Ottawa t

Example Output:

> 2 0 1 2

My Output:

> 1 0 1 2

Comment: Could you update your question to include information about exactly what's wrong with your program, eg. expected output vs actual output?

Comment: I think your `for` loop with `z` is not quite right as `z` needs to run for the length of the string, not the number of strings. That is, `z < myarray[y].length()` not `z < myarray.length`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count amount of required character ignore case, you could use `Character.toLowerCase()` for character from string and required character. It is the same, when you do `str.toLowerCase()`, but without new string creation.

For this counting task, you do not need to modify string (like `str.replaceAll()`). In general you approach is fine, but you have some mistake in your `for` loops.

```
public class Problem {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int[] count = count(readCities(scan), readChar(scan));
            System.out.println(Arrays.stream(count)
                                     .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                                     .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        }
    }

    private static String[] readCities(Scanner scan) {
        String[] cities = new String[scan.nextInt()];

        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++)
            cities[i] = scan.next();

        return cities;
    }

    private static char readChar(Scanner scan) {
        return scan.next().charAt(0);
    }

    private static int[] count(String[] cities, char ch) {
        int[] count = new int[cities.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cities[i].length(); j++)
                if (Character.toLowerCase(cities[i].charAt(j)) == Character.toLowerCase(ch))
                    count[i]++;

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really doubt he understands that. Isn't that a higher level than he would understand?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is often best to comment using // and /* text */

Second, your counter is isn’t working because you only count to the length of the array and not the String, but by using 'String.replaceAll(String, String);' and 'String.length()' you can count it.

**This** will give your char counter an error.

Input: 2 A B t

Using the variables

• length    (int)

• myarray (String[])

• ch          (char)

```
int[] countChar(int length, String[] myarray, char ch){
    int[] result = new int [length]; // Method returns int[] result
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        result[i] = myarray[i].length -
                        myarray[i].replaceAll(ch+"", "").length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code counts the char in the String like this. Worried about uppercase and lowercase? Use String.toLowerCase() and .toUpperCase() in your input.

[String length] - [String length after replacing char]

It is sometimes helpful to look at the comments. Look at Dave's and you'll find the error.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int z=0; z<myarray.length; z++){`

change the above mentioned for loop as below

`for(int z=0; z<myarray[y].length(); z++){`

`myarray.length` will represent total number of input string(4) i.e the loop will iterate until 4th character or a string , so the 1st string is "Toronto" and loop will iterate untill second occurence of 'o' remainings will not iterate.

`myarray[y].length()` will represent the total number of charactors in a string. So now the loop will iterate all the characters of a string.